# Maximization of numer of blocks in nonseparable graph

Tags: graph-theory

A simple graph is a nonseparable graph if it has no cut-vertex. A block (or biconnected component) in a simple graph is maximal subgraph which has no cut-vertex. Let $b(H)$ denotes the number of blocks in simple graph $H.$ Given a nonseparable graph, our task is to remove a vertex, such that, the number of blocks in the resulting graph are maximum. Mathematically, let $G$ be a nonseparable graph, find a vertex $v$ such that $b(G\setminus v)\ge b(G\setminus u) \ \ \forall u,v \in V(G).$ What could be the algorithm to find such a vertex. Initially I had guessed that removing vertex with the highest degree will do so, but it fails.